# Drawing rectangle on picture box from another form's button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a form with a `picturebox` on it, and another form with a button on it. How would I `picturebox1_paint` on the first form once I press the button on the other form?

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, x.text, y.text, width.text, height.text)
End Sub
```

this is what I have, what would I need to alter to get it to work?

Comment: Are you sure you want to paint your image inside your Paint event handler? It is called every time when PictureBox1 has to repaint itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Form1, add

```vb
Sub PaintImage(rectangle As Rectangle)
    ' create image in size of PictureBox1
    Dim image As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

    ' paint on created image
    Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)
        gr.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Red), rectangle)            
    End Using

    ' display finished image in PictureBox1
    PictureBox1.Image = image
End Sub
```

and call it from the form with button:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click        
    Form1.PaintImage(New Rectangle(x, y, width, height)) ' assume we already have x, y, w, h
End Sub
```

You can delete your `Paint()` event handler shown in the question. Its purpose is to repaint `PictureBox1.Image` if its size or visibility is changed and in most cases you can leave it as it is.

Comment: the values for the x,y,width and height are on the form with the button, how would i pass those values to the other form to create the rectangle?

Comment: Answer updated. You can pass them as four independent parameters or as [Rectangle structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which is already here to help you passing rectangles. :)

Comment: awesome! - one last thing, when i press the button it deletes the whole picture and just leaves the red rectangle, how would i keep the image behind it? Many Thanks

Comment: (1) On class level, create a property (or variable, or add control `PictureBox2`...) of `Image` type to hold your original picture and store your original picture there (in designer or programatically). `Public Property OriginalImage As Image` (2) draw your original picture into your `image` variable before you draw red frame: `gr.DrawImage(OriginalImage, New Point(0,0))`